# Set values of inputs with class set in ASP.NET foreach using map in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dictionary

I have input with `costclass` class in foreach. item id's are  *size*, *cost*, *costprice*.

costprice is size * price. I use map method in `AddCost()` function.

How can I set value of input corresponding to map every third element or map with costprice that

1. every 3-th map corresponding input value is 1th * 2th input map value or
2. (168)costprice" ​ = "(168)cost" ​ * "(168)size" ​
   every element of map with costprice is multiplication of cost and size

Algorithm is get map of values with cost and price and return their multiplication to input with costprice id

How can I do this?

```html
@foreach (item in ...) {
  <input class="readonly costclass" id="(@item.ID)size" value="@(item.Size)">
  <input class="costclass"  id="(@item.ID)cost" onblur='AddCost()' value="@item.Price">
  <input class="costclass" id="(@item.ID)costprice"  value="@(item.Size* float.Parse(item.Price))">
  ...
}
```

```js
function AddCost() {
  var map = $(".costclass").map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
    //return this.id;
  });
  console.log(map);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all get itemid in javascript

```
var getItemID="@item.ID";
```

after that get value of size and price dynamically

```
var size=$('#'+getItemID+'size').val();
```

then assign value to costprice

```
$('#'+getItemID+'costprice').val(costprice)
```

Your complete code should look like this

```
function AddCost() {
                var getItemID="@item.ID";
                var size=$('#'+getItemID+'size').val();
                var cost=$('#'+getItemID+'cost').val();
                var costprice=size*cost;
                  $('#'+getItemID+'costprice').val(costprice)
               }
```

**NOTE:** I haven't tested code yet it's just logic.

Comment: OK, I would review and think about it and post result. Thanks. There should be some casting to double also. :-) Is here variant without map? and here is Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #(168)sizesize

Comment: I have thought about same logic without map but really do not know syntax. var size=$('#'+getItemID+'size').val(); returns error. What should it do? and how do you correspond item from asp to this in jquery?

Comment: I understood algorithm but do now know how to get all sizes or cost from var getItemID=this.id;. It gives me (168)size 
(168)cost 
(168)costprice 
(502)size 
(502)cost.... There should be not adding but trim.

Comment: I have tested code and it is working fine https://jsfiddle.net/qumyar10/  You just need to give proper id to your fields like id="@item.ID"+"size"

Comment: OK, but there only 3 elements. What if their count is 333 generrated in foreacg instead of 3? what name should be.I already gave them proper ID.

Comment: Also I need to correspond asp and jquery. instead of       var getItemID=1 there should be trim.

Comment: var getItemID="@item.ID"; will give you corresponding id and size and cost will be calculated for particular field by $('#'+getItemID+'size').val().

Comment: but I should remove costclass from size and costsize or this.id would outout all ud causing wrong results

Comment: OK, I would do. I understood

Comment: I do not know what names should be. All are incorrect. $('#'+getItemID+'size').val(size) gives me nothing. And I thing I should rename input

Comment: var size=$('#'+getItemID+'size').val(); used to get value and $('#'+getItemID+'size').val(size) used to assign value by size variable you should be clear about what you have to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203215/discussion-between-ankit-and-ifooi).

Comment: I get all what I need and use it. Thanks! Big Thanks! I do another things and they work fine. You have answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

try this function:

```html
function AddCost() {

  var frst=0;
  var secnd=0;
        var third=0;
  var index = 0;

        var map = $(".costclass").map(function (mIndex,mObj) {
             index++;
                if(index == 1)
             {
                 frst = $(this).val();
                    return frst;
                }
             else if(index == 2)
             {
                 secnd =$(this).val();
                    return secnd;
    }
             else if(index == 3)
             {
              index = 0;
              third = frst * secnd;
                    return third;
             }
                //console.log(a);
                //console.log(b);               
                //return this.id;
            });
            console.log(map);
 }
```

Comment: but I do not have only three elements. Count can be hundreds. and index starts from, zero. I mean not first three but every three. And then I should set it to input.

Comment: yes, that index keeps track of first, second and third of every repeated set of your elements. You can have n number of set of 3 elements(Size, Cost, CostPrice).

Comment: Thanks.  I would use it in another projects.